# How can I make SpaCy recognize all my given entities

Tags: python, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I have quite a list of patterns in JSONL format that I loaded and added to the entity ruler

```
new_ruler = EntityRuler(nlp).from_disk(project_path + "data/skill_patterns.jsonl")
nlp.add_pipe(new_ruler)
```

When I print the results: `print([(ent.text, ent.label_) for ent in doc.ents])`
My output is:

```
[('data science','SKILL|data-science'), ('CV', 'ORG'), ('Kandidaat', 'FAC'), ('één', 'CARDINAL'), ('LSTM',
 'ORG'), ('Parts', 'GPE'), ('Speech', 'GPE'), ('POS', 'ORG'), ('Entity Recognition', 'ORG'), 
('NER', 'ORG'), ('Word2vec', 'ORG'), ('GloVe', 'ORG'), ('Recursive', 'NORP'), ('Neural Networks', 'ORG'),
 ('Ensemble', 'PERSON'), ('Dynamic', 'NORP'), ('Intent detection', 'PERSON'), ('Phrase matching.-', 'ORG'),
 ('Microsoft', 'NORP'), ('Azure.-', 'ORG'), ('één', 'CARDINAL'), ('Python', 'WORK_OF_ART'),
 ('Pytorch', 'GPE'), ('Django', 'GPE'), ('GoLanguage.-', 'GPE'), ('Kandidaat', 'FAC'), ('1 november 2020', 'DATE')]
```

Now I know for a fact that for example `('Pytorch', 'GPE')` or `('Django', 'GPE')` are in my pattern list and should be recognized as `SKILL` instead of the entities they got assigned now. This goes for quite a few other 'skills' as well.

```
{"label":"SKILL|django","pattern":[{"LOWER":"django"}]}
{"label":"SKILL|pytorch","pattern":[{"LOWER":"pytorch"}]}
```

Is there someone that knows why it does not adhere to my self created entities?

Is there a way that I can prioritize my entities above the ones already in the model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution.

By adding the `new_ruler` before the NER (after parser) in the pipeline, it gives the created entities priority

```
nlp.add_pipe(new_ruler, after='parser')
```